# Unable to Center a div

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I want `img_manip_header_close` block to be centered, but it's not.

CSS:

```
 #img_manip_header_close {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    top:5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    left:125px;
}

#img_manip_header {
    height:30px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="img_manip_header">
  <div id="img_manip_header_close" onclick="window.location='index.php';">Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In which browser do you have the problem?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `inline-block`. For this, a simple `block` seems more appropriate (which is the default, so you don't need to specify it).

Comment: That why I like jsfiddle: anyone can help you by testing its own solution.

Comment: @FLCL did jsfiddle fix the flaw forcing IE to be in compat mode? (because the wrong styling most likely only exists in IE with compat mode ignoring the `margin: 0 auto;`)

Comment: oh lol readin compat as combat

Comment: @FLCL IE can be in different modes standard mode and different compatibility modes. `doctype` (and some headers that can be send) influence in which mode IE is. Depending on that the rendering and some behavior of js change (e.g. ignoring `auto` in `margin` or the absence of some js functions). And the worst thing is that an `iframe` inherits the mode of the window containing it. Which made jsfiddle nearly useless to test stylings with IE (but to be honest i don't know if they fixed by now).

Comment: @t.niese, there is a meta tag I cant remember, that forces ie not too use  this mode.

Comment: It is chrome. Firefox the same.

Comment: Actually, I am curious, why left do not work.

Comment: @Tigran, try to set position absolute/relative to make left work

Comment: @Tigran `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` have no effect on elements that are positioned  `static`, which is the default. And why do you ask `Unable to Center a div` if you want to know `why left do not work`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rqR8Z/

Comment: thats why i like html - it very fine to spend a lot of time searching  even how to align element. Cooler thing is only that when you found solution you cannot be sure that it will work in 20 modes and versions of ie.

Comment: @FLCL If you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and you take care about not nesting default `block` elements in default `inline` elements (except `a`) and if you avoid to do things like `<span />` then you are relatively save if you ignore IE 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `text-align:center;` in `#img_manip_header`

```
#img_manip_header {
     height:30px;
     width:300px;
     background-color:#DEDEDE;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: block;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align:center;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KS4Z3/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the css for `img_manip_header_close` to this:

```
#img_manip_header_close {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82Asv/

Specifically, you need to remove margins and `display:inline-block`, and add margin auto.

In fact, you don't even need `text-align:center` here.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82Asv/1/

Comment: I can not, full code is:
<div id="img_manip_header">
  <div id="img_manip_header_back">Back</div>
  <div id="img_manip_header_close" onclick="window.location='index.php';">Close</div>
  <div id="img_manip_header_next">Next</div>
 </div>

Comment: @Tigran: Strange! You should have provided that info in question itself! Anyway, here is your fiddle updated with what I think you are after: **http://jsfiddle.net/82Asv/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Lose the width on the #img_manip_header_close and change display:inline-block to display:block

Did for trick here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFHv4/

```
<div id="img_manip_header">
        <div id="img_manip_header_close" onclick="window.location='index.php';">Close</div>

    </div>



 #img_manip_header_close
{

    cursor:pointer;

}
#img_manip_header
{

    background-color:#DEDEDE;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #img_manip_header_close
{
  //lose this ->  display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    top:5px;
  //lose this ->  text-align:center;  (from what you said you want to align center 'img_manip_header_close' div not the text from inside div)
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    left:125px;
}
#img_manip_header
{
    text-align:center; //add this line, in this way you will align center the content from 'img_manip_header' which is 'img_manip_header_close' div
    height:30px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px; 
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That was the right CSS. Thanks for ideas:

```
#img_manip_header
{

    height:30px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center; 


}
#img_manip_header_back
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#img_manip_header_close
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#img_manip_header_next
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```